# View file system inode tree / table of contents via Linux CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems

Does anyone know of a good file system exploration tool? Granted I can traverse directories and stuff in a shell, but I'd like something more particular to the underlying file system structure - something that I'm able to issue more low level commands with (edit file metadata, reorganize tree, view deleted files, etc). Does anyone know of any tool I might be able to use or library in Python or C that I can do this in? If not, how about some links to explanations as to how I might be able to write something that supports this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ext[234] there is `debugfs`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'd love to find a tool that does NTFS as well though. Do you know of one?

After looking through the C file system stuff it doesn't seem like it would be all that difficult to make anyhow.